# Record audio only on one button in Android

Tags: android

I want to record and stop the voice on the same button in android application.First i have recording the voice and when the stop the record on same button , but i want to start again recording it will crash my application and getting NullPointerreference at this line **myAudioRecorder.prepare();**

This is log information.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tazeen.classnkk, PID: 853
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.Record_Audio$1.onClick(Record_Audio.java:60)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19748)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

This is my Button Code in onCreate method

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        outputFile = baseDir + "/JSON_PICTURES/" + "/recording.3gp";
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        imageRecord = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_Record);
        imageRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException
            {
                clickCount += 1;
                Log.e("clickCount ", " click !!! " + clickCount);
                if (clickCount == 1)
                {
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record);
                    try
                    {
                        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                        myAudioRecorder.start();
                        Log.e("Recording ", " Start !!!");

                        t.schedule(new TimerTask()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                txtRecordTime.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        seconds++;
                                        if (seconds == 60)
                                        {
                                            seconds = 0;
                                            minute++;
                                        }
                                        if (minute == 60)
                                        {
                                            minute = 0;
                                            hour++;
                                        }
                                        txtRecordTime.setText(""
                                                + (hour > 9 ? hour : ("0" + hour)) + " : "
                                                + (minute > 9 ? minute : ("0" + minute))
                                                + " : "
                                                + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds));
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }, 1000, 1000);
                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(clickCount == 2)
                {
                    imageRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_pause);
                    myAudioRecorder.stop();
                    myAudioRecorder.release();
                    myAudioRecorder  = null;
                    t.cancel();
                }

                if(clickCount == 2 )
                {
                    myAudioRecorder  = null;
                    clickCount = 0;
                    Log.e("(clickCount == 3 ) "," click !!! " + clickCount);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is because you are making null your AudioRecorder after use like myAudioRecorder  = null;. Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logcat trace, it says you're getting a `NullPointerException`. This is  because in the following `if` statement:

```
if(clickCount == 2 )
{
    myAudioRecorder  = null;
    clickCount = 0;
    Log.e("(clickCount == 3 ) "," click !!! " + clickCount);
}
```

you're setting the `MediaRecorder` object to `null`. When you press the button again to start a recording and go back into the `if (clickCount == 1)` statement, you're using this null object, as it has not been re-instantiated (because the code above the `onClick` listener does not run again).

Simple fix, move the initialisation code:

```
myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

into the `onClick` listener in the `if (clickCount == 1)` statement before you try and use the object again.

Alternatively, rather than destroying and reinstantiating the `MediaRecorder` object multiple times, from looking at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) I believe that after calling `release()` you can simply change the output file and use the same `MediaRecorder` object next time.

On a general code cleanup note, I can see the following improvement which would help your `onClick` listener. Instead of using a counter, use a `isRecording` boolean. When this is `false` you start a recording, and when it's `true` you can finish a recording. It'll save you the logic about bounding an integer to 2 values.